# VB.Net and google drive sdk

Tags: vb.net, google-drive-api

I have an application in VB.Net who could download and upload document on google doc.
But now google doc is become google drive.

I used this code to connect at my account.

---

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim DocServices As DocumentsService

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    logIn()
End Sub

Sub logIn()
    DocServices = New DocumentsService("DocListUploader")
    DocServices.setUserCredentials(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text)

    Dim docQuery As New DocumentsListQuery
    docQuery.NumberToRetrieve = 1
    DocServices.Query(docQuery)
    getDocList()
End Sub



Sub getDocList()
    Me.lbDocs.Items.Clear()
    Dim resultFeed As DocumentsFeed = Me.theFeed()
    Dim entry As New DocumentEntry
    For Each entry In resultFeed.Entries
        Me.lbDocs.Items.Add(entry.Title.Text)
    Next
End Sub

Function theFeed() As DocumentsFeed
    Dim query As New DocumentsListQuery()
    Dim feed As DocumentsFeed = DocServices.Query(query)
    Return feed
End Function

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim theFilename As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        Dim theEntry As DocumentEntry
        theEntry = DocServices.UploadDocument(theFilename, Nothing)
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

---

I would like do the same think but with google drive. I don't find a code in vb.net only in c# like [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-cs). 
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is still valid. Document List API is not discontinued and will access your files on Google Drive.

I don't know if an implementation of the Drive API exists in VB, if you realy want to use the Drive API, you may have to build your HTTP requests manually